# How to bind dynamic object properties in HTML in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 model data objects which I added to `$scope`. They are `$scope.MyFieldModelData`and`$scope.ScreenModelData.`

`ScreenModelData` is like:

```
0: Object
    $$hashKey: "00R"
    FieldName: "SomeLabelName"
    FieldType: "label"

1: Object   
    $$hashKey: "00R"
    FieldName: "SomeDropdownName"
    FieldType: "dropdown"
```

And `MyFieldModelData` is like:

```
SomeLabelName: "Hello World"
SomeDropdownName: Array[2]  --this contains the dropdown data
```

I have to create a table with `ng-repeat` and use these model data objects to dynamically add controls on each table row. Some of the rows will have labels, some will have dropdowns and some will have hyperlinks. But this is in completely random order, so I cannot hard code anything.

I am using the following HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="MyData in ScreenModelData">
            <td>
                <label ng-show="MyData.FieldType == 'label'">{{MyFieldModelData[{{MyData.FieldName}}]}}</label>
                <select ng-show="MyData.FieldType == 'dropdown'" 
                        ng-options="MyDDLData.Code as MyDDLData.Description for MyDDLData in MyFieldModelData[{{MyData.FieldName}}]">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This renders the table but render the label and html as: `MyFieldModelData[SomeLabelName]` and for dropdown as `MyFieldModelData[SomeDropdownName]`. But actually I wanted the actual value inside the label or the actual dropdown rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the following: AngularJS is actually very very good in evaluating expressions and even evaluating when expression is in property part of object.

My code was almost there, but was not working because I had not added `ng-model` attribute in the dropdown (though I still need to work on the label part).

Once I added that, I am getting the dropdown properly. Here is the updated code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="MyData in ScreenModelData">
            <td>
                <label ng-show="MyData.FieldType == 'label'">MyFieldModelData[{{MyData.FieldName}}]</label>
                <select ng-show="MyData.FieldType == 'dropdown'" ng-model="SomeThing"
                        ng-options="MyDDLData.Code as MyDDLData.Description for MyDDLData in MyFieldModelData[{{MyData.FieldName}}]">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Either you're using a different version of Angular or the markup shown here is not the same as you're using. Both the expressions `{{MyFieldModelData[{{MyData.FieldName}}]}}` and `MyDDLData.Code as MyDDLData.Description for MyDDLData in MyFieldModelData.{{MyData.FieldName}}` will not work and probably shouldn't. Please let me know if I'm incorrect by posting it in a plunker.

Comment: @null Thanks. Yes, there was syntax error above. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this solves everything but the `ng-option` attribute does not interpolate sub expressions. Change the ...

```
ng-options="MyDDLData.Code as MyDDLData.Description for MyDDLData in MyFieldModelData[{{MyData.FieldName}}]">
```

... to ...

```
ng-options="MyDDLData.Code as MyDDLData.Description for MyDDLData in MyFieldModelData[MyData.FieldName]">
```

Otherwise have a look at [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/L0n4qi/preview). Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/McNull/angular-febworms)

**More**:

The point Ye Liu and I were trying to make is that your markup contains errors. You cannot *nest interpolation* in angular attributes that expect an *expression*. Same goes for interpolation expressions itself; you cannot nest a `{{ }}` within a `{{ }}`. See this [simple demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/YnFUHQ?p=preview) for more info.

I'll get back to you how to do dynamic form elements.

Comment: The same can be applied to the label too: `<label ng-show="MyData.FieldType == 'label'">{{MyFieldModelData[MyData.FieldName]}}</label>`

Comment: Sorry this did not work. Really not getting how to implement this. I just want some labels and dropdowns based on some condition on the repeater. I tried to use ng-init also to create scope variables in html markup, but that also only resolves to first level.